# Find the total number of elements of the form $kd+1$ among first $n$ positive integers if $d$ divides $n$.

Tags: combinatorics

> **Suppose that $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and we are willing to find the total number of elements of the form $1+kd$ where $d$ is a divisor of $n$.**

As far I can see, we are actually searching the cardinality of the set
$$ [1+kd: k =0,1,2,\cdots ]\cap \{1,2,3,\ldots,n\}$$

The total number of such possible values of $k$ is the final count.

My guess is here: $k=n/d$ but I am unable to establish it through logical argument. I feel like some connection with quotient and remainder here will play the roles, but getting mixed up.

Can someone make it clear to me?

Comment: The elements are considered $\pmod{n}$?

Comment: Is $d$ fixed? If so you want to solve $1+kd\leq n$? It will clarify a lot if you do an example of what is what you want.

Comment: The set $\{ 1 + kd\,:\, k = 0, 1, 2, \dots \}$ is infinite. According to the title of your question, it seems you want the cardinality of the set $\{ 1 + kd\,:\, k = 0, 1, 2, \dots \}\cap \{1, 2, \dots, n\}$.

Comment: @ÉricGuirbal My apology. Yes indeed I am willing to know within the range 1 to $n$, although mistakenly forgot to write in proper way.

Comment: @Phicar  Thank you for the advice. I tied in same way and got the idea.

Comment: @KON3 Great! You should edit your question with those remarks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $n=qd$, then the integers we want are $0d+1,1d+1,\dots, (q-1)d+1$ and there are therefore $q$ options ( since $\{0,\dots, q-1\}$ is bijectable with $\{1,\dots,q\}$).

Answer (score 1):

I suppose $d$ is a *positive* divisor of $n$.
The sequence $(1 + kd)_{k\geqslant 0}$ is increasing and its first term is $1$. So, the possible values for $k$ are $0$, $1$, $\dots$, up to $\bigl[\frac{n - 1}{d}\bigr]$ where $[x]$ denotes the integer part of the real number $x$ (that is the biggest integer less or equal to $x$).
As $d$ divides $n$, we have
$$
\Bigl[\frac{n - 1}{d}\Bigr] = \frac{n - d}{d} = \frac{n}{d} - 1.
$$
Therefore the requested cardinality is $\frac{n}{d}$.